# New mic isn't even being picked up

Tags: audio, microphone

I just got a new microphone (Kaichi C-650) and my Windows 10 system will make a noise (when I plug it in) but on the Recording Devices tab of my sound settings, it shows "line in" and that's not plugged in.

I feel the problem is that there are no drivers, but when I google "Kaichi C-650", nothing of the sort comes up.

I got it from here: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Pro-Black-Condenser-Dynamic-Microphone-Mic-Sound-Studio-Recording-Shock-Mount-/391182509001?hash=item5b144b63c9.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There most likely won't be any drivers for the microphone but there definitely will be audio drivers for your motherboard. Find out your motherboard name and model and download the audio drivers for it (most likely Realtek).

Comment: Thank you, there was a disabled, disconnected device that I didn't recognize and as soon as I enabled it, it installed drivers. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Happy to help. Make sure you mark this answer as the solution. :)